# Transformers v4.x: Convert slow tokenizer to fast tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm following the transformer's pretrained model [xlm-roberta-large-xnli](https://huggingface.co/joeddav/xlm-roberta-large-xnli?text=%0A&candidate_labels=&multi_class=true) example

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification",
                      model="joeddav/xlm-roberta-large-xnli")
```

and I get the following error

```
ValueError: Couldn't instantiate the backend tokenizer from one of: (1) a `tokenizers` library serialization file, (2) a slow tokenizer instance to convert or (3) an equivalent slow tokenizer class to instantiate and convert. You need to have sentencepiece installed to convert a slow tokenizer to a fast one.
```

I'm using Transformers version `'4.1.1'`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

According to Transformers `v4.0.0` [release](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/releases/tag/v4.0.0), `sentencepiece` was removed as a required dependency. This means that

> "The tokenizers that depend on the SentencePiece library will not be available with a standard transformers installation"

including the `XLMRobertaTokenizer`. However, `sentencepiece` can be installed as an extra dependency

```
pip install transformers[sentencepiece]
```

or

```
pip install sentencepiece
```

if you have transformers already installed.

Comment: pip install sentencepiece followed by kernel/runtime restart solves the issue.

Answer (score 15):

If you are in google collab:

1. Factory reset the runtime.
2. Upgrade the pip by using the following command (pip install --upgrade pip)
3. Install sentencepiece using the following command (!pip install sentencepiece)

Comment: Yes , that's work the most important thing is to restart the session .

Answer (score 6):

The below preceding code worked for me in colab notebook

```
!pip install transformers[sentencepiece]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Tokenizers that depend on the SentencePiece library will not be available with a standard transformers installation.

You should install `sentencepiece` additionally along with transformer

```
pip install transformers[sentencepiece]
```

This is needed for slow versions of:`XLNetTokenizer`,
`AlbertTokenizer`,
`CamembertTokenizer`,
`MBartTokenizer`,
`PegasusTokenizer`,
`T5Tokenizer`,
`ReformerTokenizer`,
`XLMRobertaTokenizer`

Source: [For more information in Github](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/releases/tag/v4.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

or you can set `use_fast=False` paramater in AutoTokenizer.frompretrained()