# HuggingFace AutoTokenizer | ValueError: Couldn't instantiate the backend tokenizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, onnx, huggingface-tokenizers

Goal: Amend this [Notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/blob/main/quantization/notebooks/bert/Bert-GLUE_OnnxRuntime_quantization.ipynb) to work with **albert-base-v2** model

Error occurs in **Section 1.3**.

Kernel: `conda_pytorch_p36`. I did Restart & Run All, and refreshed file view in working directory.

---

There are 3 listed ways this error can be caused. I'm not sure which my case falls under.

Section 1.3:

```py
# define the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        configs.output_dir, do_lower_case=configs.do_lower_case)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-1f864e3046eb> in <module>
    140 # define the tokenizer
    141 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
--> 142         configs.output_dir, do_lower_case=configs.do_lower_case)
    143 
    144 # Evaluate the original FP32 BERT model

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    548             tokenizer_class_py, tokenizer_class_fast = TOKENIZER_MAPPING[type(config)]
    549             if tokenizer_class_fast and (use_fast or tokenizer_class_py is None):
--> 550                 return tokenizer_class_fast.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    551             else:
    552                 if tokenizer_class_py is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
   1752             use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
   1753             cache_dir=cache_dir,
-> 1754             **kwargs,
   1755         )
   1756 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in _from_pretrained(cls, resolved_vocab_files, pretrained_model_name_or_path, init_configuration, use_auth_token, cache_dir, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
   1880         # Instantiate tokenizer.
   1881         try:
-> 1882             tokenizer = cls(*init_inputs, **init_kwargs)
   1883         except OSError:
   1884             raise OSError(

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/models/albert/tokenization_albert_fast.py in __init__(self, vocab_file, tokenizer_file, do_lower_case, remove_space, keep_accents, bos_token, eos_token, unk_token, sep_token, pad_token, cls_token, mask_token, **kwargs)
    159             cls_token=cls_token,
    160             mask_token=mask_token,
--> 161             **kwargs,
    162         )
    163 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    116         else:
    117             raise ValueError(
--> 118                 "Couldn't instantiate the backend tokenizer from one of: \n"
    119                 "(1) a `tokenizers` library serialization file, \n"
    120                 "(2) a slow tokenizer instance to convert or \n"

ValueError: Couldn't instantiate the backend tokenizer from one of: 
(1) a `tokenizers` library serialization file, 
(2) a slow tokenizer instance to convert or 
(3) an equivalent slow tokenizer class to instantiate and convert. 
You need to have sentencepiece installed to convert a slow tokenizer to a fast one.
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I can add to post.

Comment: [Git Issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/15136)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I had to `pip install sentencepiece`.

However, in the same code line, I was getting an error with `sentencepiece`.

Wrapping `str()` around both parameters yielded the same Traceback.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1f864e3046eb> in <module>
    140 # define the tokenizer
    141 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
--> 142         configs.output_dir, do_lower_case=configs.do_lower_case)
    143 
    144 # Evaluate the original FP32 BERT model

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    548             tokenizer_class_py, tokenizer_class_fast = TOKENIZER_MAPPING[type(config)]
    549             if tokenizer_class_fast and (use_fast or tokenizer_class_py is None):
--> 550                 return tokenizer_class_fast.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    551             else:
    552                 if tokenizer_class_py is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
   1752             use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
   1753             cache_dir=cache_dir,
-> 1754             **kwargs,
   1755         )
   1756 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in _from_pretrained(cls, resolved_vocab_files, pretrained_model_name_or_path, init_configuration, use_auth_token, cache_dir, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
   1776                 copy.deepcopy(init_configuration),
   1777                 *init_inputs,
-> 1778                 **(copy.deepcopy(kwargs)),
   1779             )
   1780         else:

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in _from_pretrained(cls, resolved_vocab_files, pretrained_model_name_or_path, init_configuration, use_auth_token, cache_dir, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
   1880         # Instantiate tokenizer.
   1881         try:
-> 1882             tokenizer = cls(*init_inputs, **init_kwargs)
   1883         except OSError:
   1884             raise OSError(

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/models/albert/tokenization_albert.py in __init__(self, vocab_file, do_lower_case, remove_space, keep_accents, bos_token, eos_token, unk_token, sep_token, pad_token, cls_token, mask_token, sp_model_kwargs, **kwargs)
    179 
    180         self.sp_model = spm.SentencePieceProcessor(**self.sp_model_kwargs)
--> 181         self.sp_model.Load(vocab_file)
    182 
    183     @property

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentencepiece/__init__.py in Load(self, model_file, model_proto)
    365       if model_proto:
    366         return self.LoadFromSerializedProto(model_proto)
--> 367       return self.LoadFromFile(model_file)
    368 
    369 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentencepiece/__init__.py in LoadFromFile(self, arg)
    169 
    170     def LoadFromFile(self, arg):
--> 171         return _sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor_LoadFromFile(self, arg)
    172 
    173     def DecodeIdsWithCheck(self, ids):

TypeError: not a string
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1f864e3046eb> in <module>
    140 # define the tokenizer
    141 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
--> 142         configs.output_dir, do_lower_case=configs.do_lower_case)
    143 
    144 # Evaluate the original FP32 BERT model

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    548             tokenizer_class_py, tokenizer_class_fast = TOKENIZER_MAPPING[type(config)]
    549             if tokenizer_class_fast and (use_fast or tokenizer_class_py is None):
--> 550                 return tokenizer_class_fast.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *inputs, **kwargs)
    551             else:
    552                 if tokenizer_class_py is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
   1752             use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
   1753             cache_dir=cache_dir,
-> 1754             **kwargs,
   1755         )
   1756 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in _from_pretrained(cls, resolved_vocab_files, pretrained_model_name_or_path, init_configuration, use_auth_token, cache_dir, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
   1776                 copy.deepcopy(init_configuration),
   1777                 *init_inputs,
-> 1778                 **(copy.deepcopy(kwargs)),
   1779             )
   1780         else:

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in _from_pretrained(cls, resolved_vocab_files, pretrained_model_name_or_path, init_configuration, use_auth_token, cache_dir, *init_inputs, **kwargs)
   1880         # Instantiate tokenizer.
   1881         try:
-> 1882             tokenizer = cls(*init_inputs, **init_kwargs)
   1883         except OSError:
   1884             raise OSError(

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/models/albert/tokenization_albert.py in __init__(self, vocab_file, do_lower_case, remove_space, keep_accents, bos_token, eos_token, unk_token, sep_token, pad_token, cls_token, mask_token, sp_model_kwargs, **kwargs)
    179 
    180         self.sp_model = spm.SentencePieceProcessor(**self.sp_model_kwargs)
--> 181         self.sp_model.Load(vocab_file)
    182 
    183     @property

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentencepiece/__init__.py in Load(self, model_file, model_proto)
    365       if model_proto:
    366         return self.LoadFromSerializedProto(model_proto)
--> 367       return self.LoadFromFile(model_file)
    368 
    369 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentencepiece/__init__.py in LoadFromFile(self, arg)
    169 
    170     def LoadFromFile(self, arg):
--> 171         return _sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor_LoadFromFile(self, arg)
    172 
    173     def DecodeIdsWithCheck(self, ids):

TypeError: not a string
```

I then had to swap out parameters for just the model name:

```py
tokenizer = AlbertTokenizer.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2')
```

This second part is detailed on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70711835/17840900).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65431838/9592557 **pip install sentencepiece followed by kernel/runtime restart** solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installling sentencepiece will fix it, https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8963

```
 !pip install sentencepiece
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35058180)