# Convert HuggingFace slow tokenizer to a fast tokenizer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I have a model trained to disk with a slow tokenizer:

```
from transformers import convert_slow_tokenizer
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassificationa

mybert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(PATH,
                                                        local_files_only=True,
                                                        )
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(PATH, 
                                          local_files_only=True, 
                                          use_fast=True)
```

I am able to use it to tokenize like so:

```
tokenized_example = tokenizer(
    mytext,
    max_length=100,
    truncation="only_second",
    return_overflowing_tokens=True,
    stride=50
)
```

However, it is non-fast:

```
tokenized_example.is_fast
False
```

I try to convert it to fast one, which looks successful

```
tokenizer = convert_slow_tokenizer.convert_slow_tokenizer(tokenizer)
```

However, now running this gives me:

```
tokenized_example = tokenizer(
    mytext,
    max_length=100,
    truncation="only_second",
    return_overflowing_tokens=True,
    stride=50
)


TypeError: 'tokenizers.Tokenizer' object is not callable
```

How can I convert this slow tokenizer to a fast one?

I have [seen this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431837/transformers-v4-x-convert-slow-tokenizer-to-fast-tokenizer) and I have sentencepiece installed---this did not fix my issue.

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion from this issue: https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/issues/424

Answer (score 1):

@Mittenchops, the reason tokenized_example.is_fast is False, is obviously because it isn't a "FastTokenizer".
Rather than converting a slow tokenizer, you can huggingface's [FastTokenizer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertTokenizerFast) instead.

Your code would look something like this:

```
from transformers import convert_slow_tokenizer
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertForSequenceClassification

mybert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(PATH,
                                                local_files_only=True,)
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(PATH, 
                                      local_files_only=True, 
                                      use_fast=True)

tokenized_example = tokenizer(
mytext,
max_length=100,
truncation="only_second",
return_overflowing_tokens=True,
stride=50)

# In this case: tokenized_example.is_fast will yield True
```

Comment: This is just using the fast tokenizer.  You are not converting the slow tokenizer to a fast tokenizer.

Comment: Yes, why convert it when you already have it? Unless you're experimenting with conversion

Comment: @Mittenchops you can refer to https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/error-with-new-tokenizers-urgent/2847/5, if it works for you